# How to use the "N" prefix for Unicode strings (T-SQL) in HQL?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, hql

I have this MS SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tags_synonyms WHERE TITLE LIKE N'piece'"
```

How to convert it to HQL?

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tags_synonyms WHERE TITLE LIKE N:piece";
query.setString("piece", "%" + piece + "%");
```

catch exception:

```
Invalid column name 'N@P0'.
```

Comment: query.setParameter("piece", "%" + piece + "%"); don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) then you shouldn't have to worry about the `N'` prefix on strings that we often see in pure T-SQL queries. If your Java project is set up to use Unicode strings (e.g., by using UTF-8 encoding for your Java source files) then the JDBC driver will take care of the `N'` prefix for you.

For example, the following Java code

```java
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
    try (PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT language FROM vocabulary WHERE phrase LIKE ?")) {
        s.setString(1, "%γιορτή%");
        try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("language"));
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

results in the following statement being sent to the SQL Server (as seen in SQL Profiler):

```sql
exec sp_prepexec 
    @p1 output,
    N'@P0 nvarchar(4000)',
    N'SELECT language FROM vocabulary WHERE phrase LIKE @P0        ',
    N'%γιορτή%'
```

Comment: Thx. But i'm use:         String sql = "SELECT * FROM tags_synonyms WHERE TITLE LIKE :piece"; query.setParameter("piece", "%" + piece + "%");

Comment: You mentioned that in your comment to the question, but all you said was that it "don't work". Have you confirmed that your HQL query results in the SQL Server receiving a T-SQL statement that *does not* include the `N'` prefix?

Comment: I tested this request with an empty database. Sorry =\